# Use a stored procedure in IF EXISTS method instead of select statement

Tags: sql-server

I would love to reuse a stored procedure in this situation instead of rewriting the code

```
    IF EXISTS (EXEC [dbo].[SP_JobStop_FindJobByAll] WITH (updlock,serializable)
        --IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [EZPassDataDB].[dbo].[JobPass] AS [o] WITH (updlock,serializable)
        --WHERE [o].[jobNumber] = @jobNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the resultset from the stored procedure into a temp table or table variable with `INSERT ... EXEC`, eg:

```
declare @jobs table(...)

insert into @jobs(...)
exec [dbo].[SP_JobStop_FindJobByAll]

if exists (select * from @jobs)
begin
  . . .
end
```

Comment: @Ruffone Did this answer your question?